# How to delete child from a node in Firebase in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[I want to delete this node.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaN4a.jpg)

```
 reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("GroupDetails").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("groupMembers").child(chatModel.getId()).removeValue();
```

This above code I am using.

Comment: Have you tried using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("GroupDetails").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("groupMembers").child("1").removeValue();
`?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried it and it's working but the index you are passing how can I get that index of a particular value because I want to delete value according to Id that is given.

Answer (score 1):

To remove data:

```
firebase.child(id).removeValue();
```

You might do well to have a look at the Firebase documentation for Android btw, which covers this and many more topics.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment:

> I want to delete the value according to the Id that is given.

To solve this, you need to loop through the `groupMembers` node to get the corresponding child, call `getRef()`, and remove it.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference groupMembersRef = rootRef.child("GroupDetails").child(uid).child("groupMembers");
groupMembersRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String value = ds.getValue(String.class);
                if(value.equals(chatModel.getId())) {
                    ds.getRef().removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

The result of the above code will be the removal of the second child.

Be sure to have the latest version of the Firebase Realtime Database SDK, as get() was recently added.

Comment: It worked but another problem arise is the node index which is deleted now the values in group members nodes are starting from index 1. Why it's not updating the index from 0 again.

Comment: Because your `groupMembers` in the database it's an array. This kind of data-structure is **not** dynamic, meaning that when an element from a specific index is deleted, it remains empty. More info, [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).